# how do you hide ssh console with c++?

Tags: winapi, ssh, console

I'm using an .id_rsa file to access a user account, and I don't need it as soon as it accesses it. but I need it to keep accessing the account. I want to hide the console but don't know how. how do you do it?

```
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    FreeConsole();
    system("ssh -L0000:proxy.com:0000 -i example.id_rsa user@00.00.0.000");
    return 0;
}
```

It asks for a passphrase for key 'example.id_rsa':
then, it stays on console as example:~user$

Comment: `FreeConsole` Detaches the calling process from its console. But `system` may create a new process for the ssh console. You could get the ssh console window handle first, and then use [`ShowWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow) with `SW_HIDE` to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague, but if I understood your question correctly, you want to keep the ssh connection open because of the port-forwarding that it does, but don't want it to run any shell.

The solution in such is to use the "`-f`" and "`-N`" options together, i.e., "`ssh -fN -L ...`". The "-f" ensures that ssh goes to the background but only *after* asking you for the password. The "-N" asks not to execute any command remotely (not the shell and not anything else) - and just do the port forwarding.

Comment: yes that is exactly what I want to do. but it spit out an error when I put a -f before the -L. It said "Cannot fork into background without a command to execute. what should I do?

Comment: Did you also use -N? Please do. If it still doesn't work please post a complete command line.

Comment: I think it worked, but I don't think it was what I wanted. I wanted to hide the command console as a whole, and not just the command line.

Comment: kind of what the FreeConsole() function does to other c++ files

Comment: It appears to be a Windows-specific question why the console doesn't go away as soon as ssh returns. Maybe ssh needs to call FreeConsole() before moving itself to the background, and doesn't? It might be a bug in SSH in windows...

Comment: oh...so,it's not possible?

Comment: @PY_NEWBIE have you tried `ShowWindow` to hide the console?

Comment: Are you able to get the window handle of the console with spy++?  then you could use [`FindWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa) with window name, or using the [`EnumThreadWindows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumthreadwindows) to get the console window handle, then call `ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE)`